# Insert a skewed element at the bottom of the HTML page using only CSS

Tags: html, css, skew

How to create a skewed elemnt in html page.
HTML code:

```
       <div id="Fleet">
        <div class="section Fleet_section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1>FLEET</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 
                    <div class="row top-buffer">
                        
                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail Staffinview1 delay0_5s">
                          <img src="./images/xxx.jpg">
                          <div class="caption">
                            <h3>xxx</h3>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    

                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail Staffinview1 delay1s">
                          <img src="./images/yyy.jpg">
                          <div class="caption">
                            <h3>yyy</h3>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>


                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail Staffinview1 delay1_5s">
                          <img src="./images/zzz.jpg">
                          <div class="caption">
                            <h3>zzz</h3>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                        
                    </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and css for class and id's in the code above:

```
        .section{
           width: 100%;
           height: 100%;
           padding-top: 80px;
           background-repeat: no-repeat;
           background-attachment: fixed;
           background-size: cover;
           background: #fff;
           }

       #Fleet  {
           font-size: 1.2em;
           text-align: center;
           background: #0C142b;
       }


       .thumbnail {
           border: 1px solid #0C142b;
       }

       .thumbnail>img, .thumbnail a>img {
           margin-right: auto;
           margin-left: auto;
           border-radius: 4px;
       }
```

In addition to that the bootstrap is used to format the layout

I would like to add  skewed element at the bottom, similar effect like in the exapmle linked below:
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/skewed-edges-css/

How to prepare a css styling. What html tag should looks like

Comment: `.section.Fleet:after` what is this? There is no such element in your html code. And read about pseudo elements. You need two colons. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp

Comment: Hi thanks for finding mistake. Hovewer today i back to topic and make some changes in code order and classes. I'm stil looking for solution of the same isse - corrected code you can find at the top it was edited.

Comment: @danny3b [not for `:after`.](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements)

Answer (score 0):

`#Fleet::after` ruleset is missing its `}` and has no `display: block;`. It also lacks dimensions, e.g. `width:100%;height:100%;`